# Azure Data Factory | Salesforce| Copy Activity | Duplicates_Detected

Tags: azure, duplicates, salesforce, azure-data-factory

Trying to Bulk Copy data from a legacy system (SQL Server) to Salesforce Cloud using Azure Data Factory(ADF) "Copy Data" Activity. During the Copy process, ADF fails with Salesforce error "Duplicates_Detected: Use one of these records?"

When using Salesforce API there is an option to set DuplicateRuleHeader to allow duplicate save but with ADF, I do not see this option in ADF.

Anyone came across this scenario and anyway to set allow duplicates during bulk copy?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Salesforce does not allow duplicate records to be created, and the ADF Salesforce connector in Copy Data activity does not provide an option to set the `DuplicateRuleHeader`.

**Workaround**:
As a workaround,you may utilize `Upsert` operation instead of the `Insert` operation to copy data to Salesforce. The `Upsert` operation allows you to insert new records or update existing records based on a specified external ID field.

By using the `Upsert` operation, you can avoid errors related to duplicate records and ensure that new records are inserted and existing records are updated based on the external ID field.

But this sounds like a feature request to ADF product. Hence would recommend logging a feature request item in ADF IDEAS forum here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c. All the feedback shared in IDEAS forum are actively monitored and reviewed by respective product owners and will take action based on the priority.